# about ubuntu and vlan /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, vlan

I have an ubuntu server and I want to set a static ip for it.

The ip will be 192.168.1.7, the subnet mask 255.255.255.0 the gateway 192.168.1.1 and the VLAN 50.

What lines should be in /etc/network/interfaces file to get that vlan setting and those ip subnet-mask and gw settings?

Is it correct to connect the server to a port tagged vlan 50 or shoul I connect it to a port that carries all vlans?

should this work?

```
auto eth1.50
iface eth1.50 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    vlan-raw-device eth1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your example would work, but can show you my configuration that works fine.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 0.0.0.0

vlan-raw-device eth1

auto eth1.50
iface eth1.50 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

As you see, first I bring up the unaddressed eth1, then set `vlan-raw-device` globally (that will apply to all following VLAN subinterfaces), and finally bring up the actual 802.1q vlan subinterface.

It does not matter if the port on the switch is a trunk with all vlans or just this one (50). What matters is that frames on that port are **tagged**. Frames not belonging to vlan 50 would be skipped anyway.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will let you know once i can test it. i will try 
`source /etc/network/interfaces.d/* 
 
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

 
auto eno1

iface eno1 inet static

        address 0.0.0.0



vlan-raw-device eno1



auto eno1.50


iface eno1.50 inet static

    address 192.168.1.7

    netmask 255.255.255.0

    gateway 192.168.1.1 `